# Is the sentence 'My better days, in my childhood, passed by so fast.' right?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence:

> My better days, in my childhood, passed by so fast.

right?

If the sentence is wrong, what is the right sentence in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "right?" It is very evocative and almost poetic.

Comment: The days belonged to your childhood. You can rephrase the sentence and eliminate all the commas: The better days of my childhood passed by so fast.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct.

The subject is "My better days", "in my childhood" is a parenthesis, understood to be equivalent to a relative clause "which were in my childhood". The verb phrase is "passed by", and "so fast" is adverbial.

There is a little ambiguity (which is not always bad) Do you imply "all your better days were in your childhood" or "the better days that were in your childhood passed quickly whereas the better days as an adult did not". The comma before "in" suggests the first interpretation.

You might like to compare with "My better childhood days..." or "My better days, that is my childhood"

Answer (score 0):

The commas change the meaning of the written text.

1. My better days in my childhood went by so fast.
2. My better days, in my childhood, went by so fast.

1 refers to the better days of your childhood.

2 emphasizes either that
a) it was the better days of your *childhood* only which went by quickly (at other times of your life, old age, middle age, the better days might have gone by slowly) or
b) you have had good days but only as a child.

The commas there represent pauses on either side of the phrase "in my childhood" and those pauses isolate the phrase; the effect of such isolation is to distinguish that phase from other phases of your life, either because the passage of time was different in those other phases, or because all of your good days happened during your childhood.